# Dictionary-like data structure. Is this a good practice?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, dictionary

I need a data structure to store different type of objects.E.g. `String`, `Boolean` and other classes.
Is using a `Map<String, Object>` where using the key you get the according object which assumes that you know how to cast it a good practice?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Better practice would be to use a proper object class.  This is not always possible however.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:I need to map to different type of objects.Or switch to a more suitable datastructure?Which one though?

Comment: Its not possible to tell without more details but often when people use `Map<String, Object>` they could have used a custom class, in which case the class is *much* better.

Comment: Less the casting, better the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a perfect use case for a `PropretyHolder` I wrote a while ago. You can read in length about it on [my blog](http://koblik.blogspot.ch/2012/09/keyvalue-in-memory-storage-for-java.html). I developed it with immutability in mind, feel free to adapt it to your needs.

In general I'd say if you want to profit from type safety in Java you need to know your keys. What I mean by that - it will be hardly possible to develop type safe solution where keys come from external source.

---

Here's a special key that knows type of its value (it's not complete please [download the source](https://sites.google.com/site/ivankoblik/web-storage/KVStore.zip) for complete version):

```
public class PropertyKey<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final String name;

    public PropertyKey(Class<T> valueType, String name) {
        this.clazz = valueType;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean checkType(Object value) {
        if (null == value) {
            return true;
        }
        return this.clazz.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass());
    }

    ... rest of the class

}
```

Then you develop a data structure that utilizes it:

```
public class PropertyHolder {

    private final ImmutableMap<PropertyKey<?>, ?> storage;

    /**
     * Returns value for the key of the type extending-the-one-declared-in-the {@link PropertyKey}.
     * 
     * @param key {@link PropertyKey} instance.
     * @return Value of the type declared in the key.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Serializable> T get(PropertyKey<T> key) {
        return (T) storage.get(key);
    }

    /**
     * Adds key/value pair to the state and returns new 
     * {@link PropertyHolder} with this state.
     * 
     * @param key {@link PropertyKey} instance.
     * @param value Value of type specified in {@link PropertyKey}.
     * @return New {@link PropertyHolder} with updated state.
     */
    public <T> PropertyHolder put(PropertyKey<T> key, T value) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(key, "PropertyKey cannot be null");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(value, "Value for key %s is null", 
                key);
        Preconditions.checkArgument(key.checkType(value), 
                "Property \"%s\" was given " 
                + "value of a wrong type \"%s\"", key, value);
        // Creates ImmutableMap.Builder with new key/value pair.
        return new PropertyHolder(filterOutKey(key)
                .put(key, value).build());
    }

    /**
     * Returns {@link Builder} with all the elements from the state except for the given ket.
     * 
     * @param key The key to remove.
     * @return {@link Builder} for further processing.
     */
    private <T> Builder<PropertyKey<? extends Serializable>, Serializable> filterOutKey(PropertyKey<T> key) {
        Builder<PropertyKey<? extends Serializable>, Serializable> builder = ImmutableMap
                .<PropertyKey<? extends Serializable>, Serializable> builder();
        for (Entry<PropertyKey<? extends Serializable>, Serializable> entry : this.storage.entrySet()) {
            if (!entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                builder.put(entry);
            }
        }
        return builder;
    }

    ... rest of the class

}
```

I omit here a lot of unnecessary details please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Please consider, posting the relevant code here to make your answer self-contained.

Comment: @Ivan:I don't understand this part: `return new PropertyHolder(filterOutKey(key).put(key, value).build());`

Comment: @Ivan:Shouldn't you also override `equals` and `hashCode` to use `PropertyHolder` as a key in your map?

Comment: @Jim PropertyHolder is an immutable class, I use Guava immutable collections internally, filterOutKey gives builder as a copy of Immutable map with the given key removed. Then I add new key/value pair and build the new map.

Comment: @Jim PropertyHolder is a kind of map.

Comment: @Ivan:`PropertyKey` is the key right?Shouldn't you override `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: PropertyKey is 120 lines long, I didn't want to post it here. It does implement these methods, please [download the source](https://sites.google.com/site/ivankoblik/web-storage/KVStore.zip) linked from my blog for full reference. I this answer I'm describing the idea not the full solution.

Comment: @Ivan:It seems that `put` and `get` are using the same instance variable. E.g. your `INTEGER_KEY`.What I would like is to create somewhere in the code a `PropertyKey` at runtime and `get` that somewhere else at runtime.It seems that using your construct I would need to do a cast for this.Am I right here?Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Jim I think it depends on whether 2 parts of your project know type of the value. If they do then they will use `PropertyKey<Integer>` knowing full well type of the value and cast will not be needed (implicit cast happens in `get` but it's somewhat secure). I'd also like to add that if you construct Keys on the fly you might want to add type check to `get` method or change `hashCode` & `equals` in `PropertyKey`. Right now they are based on name.

Comment: @Ivan:Why it is not possible to do `new LinkedHashMap<PropertyKey<? extends Serializable>, Serializable>()` and instead you are doing `new LinkedHashMap<K, V>()`;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16692/discussion-between-ivan-and-jim)

Answer (score 2):

A `typesafe heterogeneous container` can be used for this purpose:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Container {

    private Map<Class<?>, Object> container = new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();

    public <T> void putElement(Class<T> type, T instance) {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Type is null");
        }
        //container.put(type, instance); // 'v1'
        container.put(type, type.cast(instance)); // 'v2' runtime type safety!
    }

    public <T> T getElement(Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(container.get(type));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Container myCont = new Container();
        myCont.putElement(String.class, "aaa");
        myCont.putElement(Boolean.class, true);
        myCont.putElement(String[].class, new String[] {"one", "two"});

        System.out.println(myCont.getElement(String.class));
        System.out.println(myCont.getElement(String[].class)[1]);

    }

}
```

Limitation: this container in its form is capable only to store *one instance/object* type.

In `putElement()` you can achieve **runtime type safety** by using a dynamic cast. This will hoewever add an extra overhead.

E.g: Try to pass a raw class object to the container. Note where the exception occurs:

```
Class raw = Class.forName("MyClass");
myCont.putElement(raw, "aaa"); //ClassCastException if using 'v2'
System.out.println(myCont.getElement(raw)); //ClassCastException if using 'v1'
```

Comment: Cool. What would be the most common use case for it?

Comment: I don't understand why you cast `instance` to `type` in `putElement`. It's already guaranteed to be of type `T` (unless you're expecting to call this using reflection). Also, am I right in thinking you can only have one instance object saved per type? While that doesn't go against what the OP has described per se, I think it's likely he might want to store more than one `String` for example. Would be worth mentioning that caveat.

Comment: @Ivan:
The idea of this pattern is to `parameterize` the key instead of the container itself. This gives you more flexibility if you are dealing with different objects. One common use case can be a container for storing a DB table's row which can have different column types and you want to have access them in a `typesafe` manner.

Comment: @LorandBendig:But this way I can only add one member of type `String`.Right?

Comment: @Jim yes see 'Limitation' in my answer. Probably you want to store more instances of the same type but this wasn't stated explicitly in the question

Comment: What you could do is make the `Class<T>` key fetch you a `Map<String, T>`, and allow two parameters to define the entry: `putElement(String.class, "firstKey", "firstValue");` and `getElement(String.class, "firstKey");`. This would even allow you to store different types for the same key (such as `String.class, "max", "5"`, `Integer.class, "max", 5`, `Float.class, "max" 5.0f`, etc. though I'm not sure whether you'd want that or not. It likely increases probability of messing something up and getting a `ClassCastException`.