# How can I add to unbounded lists? (Generics)

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I am interested in doing the following:
Build a `Map<SomeObject<?>, ?>`. I thought to use 2 lists to add the keys and values:

```
List<SomeObject<?>> keys;  
List<?> values;
```

But I don't know how to add objects in this list. Any ideas?
This is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421301/dictionary-like-data-structure-is-this-a-good-practice) using @Ivan idea

Comment: What have you tried and why hasn't it worked?  This seems ridiculously simple so an example might be in order to show what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @bdares:I did not say it doesn't work.I said I don't know how to build the lists which will contain different types of objects (mixed lists)

Comment: My intention is to build the lists and populate a map based on @Ivan's idea in the link I provided

Answer (score 1):

> Each entry could be different but key-value pair must be of same T

You can't do this using the field declaration alone.

What you can do is provide getter/ setters which perform the checking on a per entry basis.

```
final Map<Class, Object> classObjectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Class, Object>();

public <T> void putMap(Class<T> tClass, T t) {
    classObjectMap.put(tClass, t);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T getMap(Class<T> tClass) {
    return (T) classObjectMap.get(tClass);
}
```

The field itself doesn't provide the checking because you can't define the relationship on a per entry basis. With getters and setters you can ensure the types are correct and provided you only use those it will work as expected.

---

The type you have chosen means you can't add to them. I would make the type allow additions. You can use type erasure to work around the problem, but this is not ideal.

> I did not say it doesn't work.I said I don't know how to build the lists which will contain different types of objects (mixed lists)

You can have a `List<Object>` which can contain any object. Or more simply just `List`.

Collections of unrelated mixed types is rarely a good idea. It usually means you are avoiding creating a custom class as you DVO or DTO.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: If I do: `List<SomeObject<T>>` would I be able to add *any* kind of `SomeObject`?

Comment: You can use `List<SomeObject>` which will produce a warning you can suppress.

Comment: I am trying to build the 2 lists so as to populate the `Map` based on another answer.What would be the best solution to build this kind of `Map` then?

Comment: Do you want to build a map of `Map<SomeType<T>, T>` where the `T` must match but can be different for different keys?

Comment: :Exactly that!Yes.Each entry could be different but key-value pair must be of same `T`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add objects to for example a `List` which has a wildcard `?` for its generic type.

That's because there's no way for the compiler to check if the object that you'd add is allowed for the actual type of the collection. For example:

```
// A List that should only contain strings
List<?> list = new List<String>();

// This is not allowed, because the compiler only knows that 'list'
// is a List<?>; so it can't be sure here that integers are allowed in the list
list.add(123);
```

See [Which methods and fields are accessible/inaccessible through a reference variable of a wildcard parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ304) in Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ for a longer explanation with an example.

Comment: But I know this.That is why I ask how to solve my particular problem

Comment: @Jim Why are you using wildcards anyway, instead of giving your method or class a generic type parameter `T`?

Comment: Because they could be of diffferent types in the map

Comment: Then you should just use raw types, or use `Object` or another common supertype instead of `?`. Note that `?` means: object from some definite but unknown type; i.e. all objects in a `List<?>` must be of the same type; you just don't know what that type is. You can't store objects of different types in a `List<?>`.

Comment: See: [What is the difference between a Collection<?> and a Collection<Object>?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ005)

Answer (score 0):

basicly you *can* do that, but with little trick - since you know size of keys and values, you may use "toArray" method on map.keys() and map.values(). this will give you 2 arrays

```
    class Key<T> {
    }
    Map<Key<?>, ?> map = new HashMap<Key<?>, Object>();
    Key[] keyz = map.keySet().toArray(new Key[0]);
    Object[] values = map.values().toArray(new Object[0]);
    List<Key<?>> lstKey = Arrays.<Key<?>>asList(keyz);
    List<?> lstVal = Arrays.asList(values);
```

arrays in Java are covariant, that makes it possible.